# Superset on Kubernetes with Helm not using custom values file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

I'm trying to install Apache Superset on a Kubernetes Cluster (AWS EKS) using Helm and following the official procedure described [here](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes).

```
bash-3.2$ helm repo add superset https://apache.github.io/superset
"superset" has been added to your repositories

bash-3.2$ helm search repo superset
NAME                CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION                                       
superset/superset   0.1.2           1.0         Apache Superset is a modern, enterprise-ready b...
```

Since I want to use RDS and ElastiCache for database and cache respectively, instead of the bundled postgresql and redis, I need to override several values in the default `values.yaml` so I  made a copy of the default values

```
bash-3.2$ helm show values superset/superset > custom-values.yaml
```

edited several sections such as

```
postgresql:
  ##
  ## Use the PostgreSQL chart dependency.
  ## Set to false if bringing your own PostgreSQL.
  enabled: false

[...]

  ##
  ## If you are bringing your own PostgreSQL, you should set postgresHost and
  ## also probably service.port, postgresqlUsername, postgresqlPassword, and postgresqlDatabase
  postgresHost: myproject.cluster-xxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

and others, and installed my release with

```
bash-3.2$ helm upgrade --install --values custom-values.yaml superset superset/superset
```

as described in the guide.

The first three pods are created:

```
bash-3.2$ kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
superset-7d96fc8787-vr6c6          0/1     Init:0/1   0          3m4s
superset-init-db-xqmd9             0/1     Init:0/1   0          3m3s
superset-worker-7fff4f497b-cnqs5   0/1     Init:0/1   0          3m4s
```

but then nothing happens. Logging in into the `init-container` of the `superset-init` pod I discovered that the process waiting for the database to become available is stuck because it is using the default environment variables instead of those I provided in the `custom-values.yaml` file:

```
bash-3.2$ kubectl exec -it --container wait-for-postgres superset-init-db-xqmd9 -- sh
/ # 
/ # env
REDIS_PORT=6379
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://172.20.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
HOSTNAME=superset-init-db-xqmd9
DB_PORT=5432
SUPERSET_PORT=tcp://172.20.72.4:8088
SUPERSET_SERVICE_PORT=8088
SUPERSET_PORT_8088_TCP_ADDR=172.20.72.4
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
DB_NAME=superset
SUPERSET_PORT_8088_TCP_PORT=8088
SUPERSET_PORT_8088_TCP_PROTO=tcp
SUPERSET_PORT_8088_TCP=tcp://172.20.72.4:8088
TERM=xterm
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=172.20.0.1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
DB_PASS=superset
SUPERSET_SERVICE_PORT_HTTP=8088
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://172.20.0.1:443
REDIS_HOST=superset-redis-headless
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=172.20.0.1
PWD=/
DB_HOST=superset-postgresql
SUPERSET_SERVICE_HOST=172.20.72.4
DB_USER=superset
```

EDIT:

some of the custom values in the `custom-values.yaml` file are actually used to override the defaults. E.g:

```
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
```

instead of

```
service:
  type: ClusterIP
```

and also postgresql and redis pods are not created when I set them as `enabled: false` but for some reason other custom values are not applied or passed to the secret storing env variables for the pods.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @nolw38, after I destroyed the environment and rebuilt it from scratch it turned out that Saikat was right (see his answer below): the right place to add your database connection details is in the supersetNode section. Probably I had completely screwed the configuration. Unfortunately I had to fall back to the local postgres configuration anyways for a different reason: queries working in SQL Editor, same queries hanging forever if saved as a chart, no error message anywhere, no help from documentation. Very frustrating. I'm thinking about opening a new thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [values.yaml](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/helm/superset/values.yaml) of **superset**,
I do see if you are bringing your own Postgres instance, from the above question as I've understood, You have to change the values of [these](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/helm/superset/values.yaml#L151-L155)

```yaml
supersetNode:
  connections:
    # Change incase bringing your own redis and then also make `redis.enabled`:false
    redis_host: '{{ template "superset.fullname" . }}-redis-headless'
    redis_port: "6379"
    # You need to change below configuration incase bringing own pg instance and as you made `postgresql.enabled`:false that's correct incase bringing own pg instance
    db_host: <YOUR RDS PG HOST>
    db_port: "5432"
    db_user: <YOUR DB USER>
    db_pass: <YOUR DB PASS>
    db_name: <YOUR DB NAME | postgres>
```

Comment: Hi Saikat, I've already edited those parameters because the documentation seemed to suggest so. Unfortunately those values do not seem to be actually used anywhere. It turned out that the only way to bring up the stack was to add DB_HOST, REDIS_HOST etc in the section extraSecretEnv. I wish that guide to provide some example configuration for a production environment.

Comment: That's odd, I can see it [here](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/helm/superset/templates/secret-env.yaml#L28-L34) and [here](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/helm/superset/values.yaml#L46)  its being passed to the env,

Comment: Hi Saikat, as I wrote in another comment, It turned out you were right. I managed to connect an RDS db to my Superset, although I had to eventually give up on that configuration for other reasons. Thank you for your help.